# Get value of object binded in cshtml in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my cshtml page I have table and few columns of tables are binded like:

```
 @Html.ReportDataPoint(new ChartDataSet { data = item.MONTHLY18THMONTHDATA, element_id = item.ITEMID, machine_id = item.SOURCEID, i = 18, speed = item.BANDWIDTH_MB, name = item.ALIAS_LOWERCASE, start = DateTimeExtensions.MonthlyGraphDate(18), end = DateTimeExtensions.MonthlyGraphDate(17), circuitid = item.CIRCUITID }, role, circuitDetails)
 @Html.ReportDataPoint(new ChartDataSet { data = item.MONTHLY17THMONTHDATA, element_id = item.ITEMID, machine_id = item.SOURCEID, i = 17, speed = item.BANDWIDTH_MB, name = item.ALIAS_LOWERCASE, start = DateTimeExtensions.MonthlyGraphDate(17), end = DateTimeExtensions.MonthlyGraphDate(16), circuitid = item.CIRCUITID }, role, circuitDetails)
```

Now in my java script file when I am iterating through the object of the table to perform some operation I am getting the values of those column as in image below. But I am able to see the value only in Quick Watch window.  [image]

But as I write "val2['@data-order']" in javascript file it shows error. I need value 0.874820.

Please help that how can I read that value from an object like this.

Comment: what is `val2` ? Where is it getting data from ?  What is the error with the code you tried ?

Comment: val2 is an object that contains the data of each row in a grid. Error is when i write val2[@data-order] to get value it is having red line. Any idea how to get the value.